# Не отправляется форма после добавления js скрипта

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть следующий html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Scale.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <title>Countries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @foreach (var country in Model)
        {
            <a class="fancybox">
                <div class="tooltip">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = country.Culture }))
                    {
                        <!-- onclick="zoomIn('@country.Culture')"-->
                        <input id="@country.Culture" class="@country.Sprite" type="image" name="submit" src="//" />
                        <span class="tooltiptext">@country.Country</span>
                    }
                </div>
            </a>
        }
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Суть заключается в том, что на экран выводятся флаги стран с тултипами и по нажатию нужно сменить язык тултипов на язык, который используется в стране. Это я сделал, а вот теперь нужно чтобы после нажатия картинка с флагом увеличивалась на весь экран, а потом уже менялся язык. Нашел скрипты fancybox, но после его вставки форма не отправляется, выбранный флаг появляется в центре, но дальше ничего не происходит, в чем может быть проблема? Я на asp и js до этого не писал ни разу

Answer (score 1):

fancybox v1.3x:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    onComplete : function() {
        this.find("form").submit();
    }
});
```

fancybox v2.x:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow : function() {
        this.find("form").submit();
    }
});
```

[API 1.3](http://fancybox.net/api)

[API 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

Comment: По ссылкам не нашел такого кода. form это имя формы? Или он ищет первую попавшуюся?

Comment: он ищет первую попавшуюся среди детей - https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Окошко с картинкой исчезает, но форма по прежнему не отправляется, даже код контроллера не вызывается

Comment: @SmiLe Что показывает отладка JS в браузере?